# Installing 13.10 alongside preinstalled Windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, gpt, fdisk

I followed this guide to a T: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

However, when I get to step 6, I just see my `/dev/sda` and it says it's completely unallocated. I could just select `/dev/sda` and click *Install now*, but wouldn't that kill my Windows installation? Quitting the installation and just running Ubuntu from the LiveUSB, GParted says the whole drive is unallocated and says I have a corrupt or invalid GPT table. Using the *Disks* utility, I can see all of my partitions, including the free space I created. Running `fdisk` says: `partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary`, and doesn't list any partitions.

I have already read through every related post on here and none of it works. Is there not some simple way to tell Ubuntu to play nice with the way Windows 8 partitions the hard drive? If there isn't a straightforward answer to this, I am abandoning the idea of ever using Linux outside of a work environment. Something with so much support and so many well-versed users should not be so difficult.

EDIT:
Here is what I get from gdisk:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.7

 Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
 backup header from main header.

 Partition table scan:
   MBR: protective
   BSD: not present
   APM: not present
   GPT: damaged

 ****************************************************************************
 Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
 verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
 ****************************************************************************

 Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
 1 blocks!
 Try reducing the partition table size by 4 entries.
 (Use the 's' item on the experts' menu.)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that one of two things is happening:

- Your disk has a [Host Protected Area (HPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area) set inappropriately, which `gdisk` is detecting as a damaged backup partition table. As described on the Wikipedia article, you can identify a disk with an HPA set via the `sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda` command in Ubuntu.
- Linux thinks the disk is part of a motherboard-based software RAID array (aka "fake RAID"), which effectively reduces its size by a small amount. The result is similar in that `gdisk` identifies the backup partition table as damaged. If this is the case, `sudo dmraid -rE /dev/sda` might fix the problem; but be *very cautious* about doing this, since if the disk really *should* have RAID active, this command may do serious damage to the disk!

If you need more help, post the output of `sudo hdparm -N /dev/sda` and some more information from `gdisk` -- specifically, the output of the `p` and `v` commands within the program.